# Image not overwriting on same name

Tags: java, android, bitmap, overwrite

I'm developing image editor app.. so each time the user have to save the image.
So first i inserted

```
  String savedImageURL = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                        getContentResolver(),
                        bitmap,
                        "Bird",
                        "Image of bird"
                );
```

this code, but it creating new file instead of overwriting.

So i use another method

```
public String saveImage(String folderName, String imageName) {
 String selectedOutputPath = "";
      if (isSDCARDMounted()) {
          File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                  Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), folderName);
          // Create a storage directory if it does not exist
          if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
              if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                  Log.d("PhotoEditorSDK", "Failed to create directory");
              }
          }
          // Create a media file name
          selectedOutputPath = mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + imageName;
          Log.d("PhotoEditorSDK", "selected camera path " + selectedOutputPath);
     File file = new File(selectedOutputPath);
     try {
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file,true);
                    if (parentView != null) {
                        parentView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                        parentView.getDrawingCache().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);
                    }
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
     }
     return selectedOutputPath;
       }
```

But it also didn't work.

Does anyone know about overwrite a bitmap in the same name?

Comment: are you facing exception Or a new file ?

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: I didnt get any error.. everything works fine but the image not overwriting in same name or file. only first saved section inserting in file the second one not overwriting.

Answer (score 1):

Pass false as 2nd argument, to set append to false, so that you will overwrite the existing file:

```
 FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file,false);
```

Check out the constructor [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29):

here is your code:

```
public String saveImage(String folderName, String imageName) {
 String selectedOutputPath = "";
    if (isSDCARDMounted()) {
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), folderName);
      // Create a storage directory if it does not exist
      if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
          if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
              Log.d("PhotoEditorSDK", "Failed to create directory");
          }
      }
      // Create a media file name
      selectedOutputPath = mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + imageName;
      Log.d("PhotoEditorSDK", "selected camera path " + selectedOutputPath);
 File file = new File(selectedOutputPath);

if (file.exists()) 
{
  try {
            file.delete();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


 try {
 file.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file,false);
                if (parentView != null) {
                    parentView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                    parentView.getDrawingCache().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);
                }
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
 }
 return selectedOutputPath;
   }
```

Comment: if you want to replace the file each time then simply delete the file and create new one.

Comment: im working on the same file without closing that section.. first i add a sticker and saved the image and chk it on gallery. it saved successfully and again i went to my app and add another sticker and saved the image. And i chked again on gallery the image doesn't change.Why is that happening?

Answer (score 1):

I also had this situation, but it turns out that this is not a problem with saving, but with displaying in ImageViev. I used **Glide**, and it turns out to be stored in the cache when outputting. And I did not change the name and path of the file. That is, I rewrote them. But **Glide** did not know this. He thought they were the same file. To fix this problem, I added the following

```
Glide.with(context)
     .load(file)
     .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
     .skipMemoryCache(true)
     .into(view)
```

If you also have this situation and these solutions helped you, I'm glad to this.